What is the significance of bowing during the doxology (Glory Be) prayer
Last year when I visited a Benedictine monastery, I noticed that all the monks were bowing during the first part of the Glory Be during their Hours.
What is the history and significance of this?  Should lay-people bow too, (or only if the Spirit moves them)?  Is it just a Benedictine thing?

Secular priests and deacons bow too, so it isn’t a Benedictine thing

Bowing at "Glory be ..." is not just a Benedictine thing; it is (or at least was) quite general. For example, the rubrics in the missal of Pope St. Pius V say, in the context of the priest's prayers at the foot of the altar, "Cum in fine Psalmi dicit 'Gloria Patri, etc.' caput Cruci inclinat." (Ritus Servandos in Celebratione Missae, Section III.6). [My translation: When at the end of the psalm he says "Glory be to the Father, etc." he bows his head toward the cross.] There's a similar instruction for the "Glory be ..." in the introit, but (curiously) I didn't find it for the "Glory be ..." after the washing of his hands.
